# Can't get Yelp API to display Business ID in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yelp

I'm trying to use the Yelp API to display a business' id

I installed the Yelp Gem as well as added my code to the initializer under Yelp.rb

```
client = Yelp::Client.new({ consumer_key: 'n8jpEPZJkbXwqAw',
                            consumer_secret: 'ABuZv6OW0iVTqPD5irr4',
                            token: 'AjYSuqleh0Ihb',
                            token_secret: 'wWaBdFu_dFXqbFc'
                          })
```

After that I went to a controller and added this

```
 def reviews
    Yelp.client.search(‘San Francisco’)

  end
```

I then tried to call the @reviews in the views and nothing is displaying

```
<%= @reviews.id %>
```

Any advice would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the response from the search call:

```
response = Yelp.client.search('San Francisco')
```

Then you can access the results in the array of businesses returned in `response`.  For example, to get the rating of the first business returned:

```
response.businesses[0].rating
```

You asked for the business ID, which of course is:

```
response.businesses[0].id
```

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it out, it was because I had the method in the wrong place :(